# How to get a rotate animation to trigger on every mouse click using Raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, rotation, raphael

So I've been working on this problem for a bit and I've hit yet another roadblock.

Essentially, I'm attempting to have a mouse click trigger a rotation animation on a set of svg objects drawn up with Raphael.js. And while I've got the actual animation solved I can't seem to get it to run on subsequent clicks...just runs the one time and thats it.

So I'd imagine there is a bit of code that I'm neglecting to include..or that possibly the animation breaks after do to the change in coordinates after the applied animation? Anyway, I'm stumped...

Here's the [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H3GGERS/A5GZL/).

Here's the code:

```
var rsr = Raphael('rsr', 320, 240),
    circle_01 = rsr.circle(160, 120, 20).attr({fill:"#666666"}),
    circle_02 = rsr.circle(160, 220, 20),
    circle_03 = rsr.circle(160, 20, 20),
    circle_04 = rsr.circle(20, 120, 20),
    circle_05 = rsr.circle(300, 120, 20),
    group = rsr.set();

group.push(
    circle_02, 
    circle_03, 
    circle_04, 
    circle_05
);

var aa = group.getBBox();

circle_01.click(function() {

    var group_x_center = aa.x + (aa.width / 2),
        group_y_center = aa.y + (aa.height / 2);

    group.animate({
        transform: group.attr("transform") + "R360," 
            + group_x_center + "," 
            + group_y_center
    }, 1000); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that problem you're seeing is that when you first run the animation, it rotates your set the desired number of degrees -- and then when the same animation is fired subsequently, it does nothing because the set has already been rotated to that angle.

I would solve this problem by appending to the transform instead of setting it absolutely:

```
group.animate({transform: group.attr("transform") + "...R45,"+group_x_center+","+group_y_center}, 1000);
```

Alternatively, you could keep track of the current angle, increment it on each click, and then set it variably -- but that'd probably be more work =)

Comment: Thanks so much! That certainly seems to be the trick! I'm still pretty new to programming/javascript so I'll have to check out appending so I can properly understand what's happening here.

Comment: @Kyle - accept Zero's answer and it will give you more chance of people answering you again